# Angular app.run possibility of keeping data in app

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

There is a possibility in app.run I record any information in this case last at $stateParams and write to the $rootScoope?

It would be simple because I pull the server a coming collection mongodb and I just editing it throughout the app.

I want to prevent in all state entries I have to pull the less data.

my app.run in test:

```
.run(function($rootScope, $state, $stateParams, CLIENTS) {

    $rootScope.$state       = $state;
    $rootScope.$stateParams = $stateParams;

    console.log($stateParams);


    CLIENTS.getList({client: client})
     .then(function(res){
         console.log(res);
     });

});
```

Follow this path:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {


        // get Client data
        if(!$rootScope.clientSet) {
            CLIENTS.getList({client: toParams.client})
            .then(function(res){
                $rootScope.clientSet = res[0];
            });
        }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#state-change-events
You can listen for events so you can refresh data in rootScope.

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', 
function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){ ... })
```

Comment: ok so what's the problem with your edit ? is this not working ? Is this missing something ?

Comment: I only edit because it follows this path, would have any suggestions the most?

Comment: I meant, your code seems fine to me so what do you need ? Do you want to add more variables ? This pattern is pretty fine. you can store $stateParams of the current route from the variable toParams